# Problems with Numpy.where function and syntax

Tags: python, arrays, conditional-statements

I am working on some code to create a table of data and have run into an issue. Early on in the code I create a range of speeds that the program needs to check with the following:

```
Vskn=np.linspace(Vl,Vh, num=int ((Vh-Vl)*2+1))
```

For each Vskn I then compute the FN and Frcrit, which are separate functions that use the Vskn list... Basically I need the FN and Frcrit for each speed.

Later on in the code I need to determine if FN or Frcrit is higher, then do some calculations to them based on that result. I have tried each of the following, and neither work.

```
np.where(FN<Frcrit[kFrm=1,kFrm=(FN/Frcrit)**c1dm])
```

Results in a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

```
#if FN<Frcrit:
#    kFrm=1
#else:
#    kFrm=(FN/Frcrit)**c1dm
```

Results in a "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use `a.any()` or `a.all()`"

How do I resolve this?

Comment: there are so many undefined variables. you need to make this example runnable if you're going to get help

Comment: yes please provide a [mre]

Comment: what is this supposed to do `Frcrit[kFrm=1,kFrm=(FN/Frcrit)**c1dm]`? I don't know of any python object that let's you index/access elements by name like that with bog standard brackets (`[]`)

Comment: Search with the error message there will be plenty of Q&A's to give you an idea of what the problem is. Basically you have asked if an array/series is  True. An array/series can be `[True,False,True]` and numerous other combinations  so the array's Truth value is ambiguous. Depending on your criteria you either need them **all** to be True or **any** of them to be True

Comment: If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features - like setting breakpoints and examining values. Or you could spend a little time and get familiar with the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Also, printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is just a little off. When using `numpy`, it's often easier to use indexing directly rather than using `where`. So, if `kFrm` *already exists*, then you can index into `kFrm` "where" `FN < Frcrit` and set it to 1, and similarly index into `kFrm` "where" `FN >= Frcrit` and set it equal to your equation. I'm also indexing into `greater_than_vals` to make the shapes work.

```
kFrm[FN < Frcrit] = 1
greater_than_vals = (FN / Frcrit) ** c1dm
kFrm[FN >= Frcrit] = greater_than_vals[FN >= Frcrit]
```

If `kFrm` doesn't exist yet, then you can do:

```
kFrm = np.ones_like(FN)
greater_than_vals = (FN / Frcrit) ** c1dm
kFrm[FN >= Frcrit] = greater_than_vals[FN >= Frcrit]
```

Comment: kFrm does not exist at this point, it is defined at this point. I tried your code and it seems to work, thank you! Now to keep debugging...

Comment: Hmmm, So now when I run the program it seems to be correct. Except when I try to print the output ```print('{:12.4f}'.format(kFrm), end='')``` it gives me the error 
  "File "/Users/RLS_LLC/Desktop/NAME 3150 - resistance/Project/Project2v3/output.py", line 145, in <module>
    print('{:12.4f}'.format(kFrm), end='')

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__"

Comment: Ya, `numpy` can't use standard formatting like that, unfortunately. If you need a specific format when printing a `numpy` array, you'll need to use [`numpy.set_printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) or the [`numpy.printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.printoptions.html) context manager. They will allow you to specify the format for printing.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to convert ```print('{:12.4f}'.format(kFrm), end='')``` to print with Numpy? I am just flailing around with this stuff (no programming background) and while I found the guide on how to use Numpy.set... I really don't even understand what it is trying to tell me.

Comment: It can be frustrating, but that's mostly because `numpy` does a lot of work to make its arrays print really nicely in pretty much all scenarios. You can set print options with `numpy.set_printoptions(formatter={"all": lambda x: "{:12.4f}".format(x)})`, then use `print(kFrm, end="")`. That should get you something like what you want.

Comment: That is amazing... I think I get how it's working. Heck if I had known that it could have saved me hours of time doing all the formatting by trial and error... But there seems to be an issue, that the column created by this creates six copies of itself.

Comment: For sure - don't forget to switch back to default printing with `numpy.set_printoptions()` (no arguments) after you're done. This is a global `numpy` switch, and may screw up the rest of your program if you're depending on `numpy`'s default printing behavior elsewhere. Check out [`numpy.printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.printoptions.html) and [context managers in Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), I think that would be the more responsible way to handle printing this line.

Comment: I am not sure what you are suggesting. The ```print (kRfm, end="")``` line is buried inside 12 other print commands handling integers. I added the Numpy formatting command at the top of the module, then the ```print (kRfm, end="")``` inline with the other commands. But for some reason it duplicates the kRfm column a bunch of times. If I cancel the Numpy options in the next line, it still prints the errant columns, they just loose all the decimals (1.0000 becomes 1.)

Comment: Hm, the printing options aren't causing the duplicated columns. Either you're printing inside of a loop, or something is happening to create "duplicated columns". I have a feeling I know what it is, but honestly messaging in SO comments is not the way to debug... I hate to say it, but maybe create a new post with the duplicating-columns issue? Try to include as much code as you can in the post - there's guidelines for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I can keep an eye on your profile if that's the option you choose, and try to help. I think that's best

Comment: I opened a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64670207/printing-a-numpy-array and yes I am printing inside a loop.